# Array key on laravel controller group by

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I want to get data plan by date, then I use carbon on laravel to get it.
this my query on laravel controller

```
 $data = DB::table('visit_plan')
                ->join('outlets', 'outlets.id', '=', 'visit_plan.id_outlet')
                ->select('outlets.id', 'outlets.name')
                ->get()
                ->groupBy(function($date) {
                    return $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::parse($date->date)->format('Y-m-d');
                });
               

    $data = $data->reverse();
```

The output json like this :

```
{
"2023-08-29": [
    {
        "id": "0e2b7c5b-c8d4-4c03-bec8-69d9eeeb7e4b",
        "name": "Basura Mall",
    },
    {
        "id": "0e2b7c5b-c8d4-4c03-bec8-69d9eeeb7e4b",
        "name": "TRANSMART KOKAS",

    }
]
```

}

But i want key in date value and event value like this :

```
{
        "tanggal": "2023-08-29",
        "event": [
            {
                "id": "01dfcdef-691c-43aa-a167-cb91b153a7e8",
                "name": "Bassura Mall "
            },
            {
                "id": "d494cdf4-7c79-4e7a-9761-c37203b7ba9c",
                "name": "TRANSMART KOKAS"
            },
            
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` your data to your wished structure. Due to it being left out mostly, the second parameter of closures on `map`, `each` and similar is the key of the array. Which you can use to get the grouped by key.

```
return $data->map(function ($events, $key) {
    return [
        'tanggal' => $key,
        'event' => $events,
    ];
});
```

A more Laravel approach is to make a setup that use [Laravel resources](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources) to do theses transformations. For the scope of this question is a little over engineered.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result like this.

```
$data = $data->toArray();
$tanggal = array_keys($data)[0];
$event = array_values($data)[0];
$data = [
  'tanggal' => $tanggal,
  'event' => $event,
];
return $data;
```